# How can I query a list of values into a column of rows using SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to take a list of names (e.g. john, mary, paul) and create a SQLite "select" query that will return this list in a column of rows.  Based on [this](http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSql), the following was stated:

"According to the SQL92 standard, a VALUES expression should be able to stand on itself. For example, the following should return a one-column table with three rows:"

```
 VALUES 'john', 'mary', 'paul';
```

In theory, the result set would look like:

```
john
mary
paul
```

But as the page seems to indicate, this is an unsupported feature in SQLite.  The only way that I can figure out how to do this is by unioning a series of select statements like so:

```
SELECT 'john' AS name
UNION ALL SELECT 'mary' AS name
UNION ALL SELECT 'paul' AS name;
```

Is this the only way to do this in SQLite or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all I know, what you have there already is the best [compound SELECT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) SQLite has to offer. One tiny thing: you need the column alias once only.

```
SELECT 'john' AS name
UNION ALL SELECT 'mary' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'paul';
```

Answer (score 0):

I found more expressive to use:

```
SELECT 'john' AS name UNION ALL VALUES ('mary'), ('paul')
```

You need to specify the first select to gain column aliases.

This construct is easier to read and has fewer limitations as stated in the sqlite documentation:

> The phrase "VALUES(expr-list)" means the same thing as "SELECT
>   expr-list". The phrase "VALUES(expr-list-1),...,(expr-list-N)" means
>   the same thing as "SELECT expr-list-1 UNION ALL ... UNION ALL SELECT
>   expr-list-N". Both forms are the same, except that the number of
>   SELECT statements in a compound is limited by
>   SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT whereas the number of rows in a VALUES
>   clause has no arbitrary limit.

Answer (score 0):

This did not work in SQLite 3.7, but works in SQLite 3.26:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('john'), ('mary'), ('paul')) ;
```

---

Unlike say PostgreSQL, however, SQLite won't let *us* alias the columns of such a rowset: SQLite *itself* names the columns as `column`, `column2`, and so on.  To assign our own aliases, we must alias SQLite's aliases:

```sql
SELECT column1 AS name, column2 AS age
FROM (VALUES ('john',33), ('mary',44), ('paul',55)) ;
```

gives

```
name        age       
----------  ----------
john        33        
mary        44        
paul        55
```